# Unable to understand errors from javascript

Tags: javascript, console

Again i have encountered another problem. I have done my best to learn from the previous mistakes but again i have to ask another question as i have ran into another problem again. I have written up more code, and that seems to have broken the whole code again.. When i am clicking my button, these errors come up in the console. I have found the lines it has errors in, and i do not see what it is having errors with. 
I have uploaded it to this. Apologies for not being able to explain better. There are notes on  the lines that the console is having trouble with. Also apologize for my terrible syntax, i am very new at programming..
http://jsfiddle.net/EUK8J/2/

This line says explore is not defined, but it has worked before.

```
<button onclick="explore()">Explore</button>
```

And here is where it is defined:

```
function explore(){
if(stam>1){
    redStam();
    refresh();
    if (rNumber<=0.33){
        stam=(stam+100);
    }
    else if (rNumber<=0.66){
        cash=(cash+100);
    }
    else    {health=(health-10);
    }
}
else{alert("You have no stamina")}}
```

Not much coding to go on here i know, but the link provided has the full code and is hopefully enough to help show my mistakes.

Comment: The function is declared inside the `load` callback in the fiddle. If you setup your fiddle correctly, it might work. *edit:* Or not, there is also a syntax error in your code and apparently you know that already. So why don't you fix it?

Comment: R.E - `document.getElementById('health') innerHTML = health; //console says uncaught syntax error:unidentified syntax` it should be `document.getElementById('health').innerHTML = health; //console says uncaught syntax error:unidentified syntax`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jsfiddle site will wrap your JavaScript code up in a function unless you explicitly tell it not to, via the second pull-down selector on the left side.  Because of that, your functions will not be global. If you use either "No wrap (in `<head>`)" or "No wrap (in `<body>`)" then it'll work.

(When I say "it'll work", what I mean is that it will at least be able to find your function.)

Comment: Who is downvoting this? This is absolutely the correct answer

Comment: Me by accident... Now it won't let me up-vote unless its edited -_-

Answer (score 0):

You just missed a dot in:

```
document.getElementById('health') innerHTML = health;
```

between `document.getElementById('health')` and `innerHTML`

Comment: Damn really.. I see that now. Okay thanks for that. Will accept as answer when it will let me in time

Comment: This is indeed an error in the fiddle but is not the root of the problem you asked about. While Uby is totally correct, it is not really answering the question you asked. I suggest looking at Pointy's answer...

Answer (score 0):

In the fiddle, you'll have to select `nowrap`...

[image]

`alert("You have no stamina")` is missing a semi-colon.

`document.getElementById('health').innerHTML = health;` was giving you a syntax error because it was missing the `.` after `('health')`.